# Webpack rebundled dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to make a JS library to play videos.
I'm starting with Dailymotion and JWPlayer.

Depending on what user want to play I'd like to dynamically load dailymotion or jwPlayer sdk.

For Dailymotion I request their SDK from a CDN so I can just add a script tag at runtime, fine.

For JWPLayer I have all the javascript, but I want it to be in a separate chunk, so I'm using dynamic imports.

In my output directory I have:

- main.bundle.js
- jwplayer.chunk.js

*webpack.config.js*:

```
const path = require('path');

const buildConfig = require('./build.config.js');
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    CorePlayer: path.resolve(srcDir, 'CorePlayer'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, buildConfig.outDirectory),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'internal/_[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
      '@lib': path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

*.babelrc*:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "loose": true,
        "shippedProposals": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Now I'm trying to request my library as a module from another project:

```
import myPlayer from 'my-player';
```

`myPlayer` is what is exported by `main.bundle.js` and will be part of this project's bundle.

But when I want to display a video using jwplayer I will get an error 404, cannot find jwplayer.chunk.js

I don't see how I should fix this, is there a way to preserve dynamic import when rebundling my library ?

Comment: Can you add your webpack config?

Comment: here it is, with my babel config. You will notice I changed some path and names for a simpler explanation of my issue

Comment: Is jwplayer.chunck.js in your build folder `buildConfig.outDirectory` after building?

Comment: yes, it is in a subdirectory of it (due to `chunkFilename: 'internal/_[name].js'`)

Comment: Ow, but it isn't available from another project right?

Comment: Do you install your module (player) as dependency in your other project?

So let's say:

`myPlayer` project add to the package.json:

`"peerDependencies": { "jwplayer": "1.0.3" }` And in your other project: `"dependencies": { "@myplayer": "x.x.x" }`

Comment: jwplayer can be self-hosted or require from a CDN. I would prefer it to be self-hosted and manually updated. I store it under a "lib" directory and I use a relative path to include it

Comment: And yes, the chunk generated by dynamic import is not available to the consumer project (which import my player as a dependency)